# Passing-variable-from-vbscript-to-batch-file with arguments

Tags: vbscript, batch-file

Please how to pass the 'inp" variable from this piece of vbs to my batch named job.bat? Indeed when doing echoing (echo %2) from job.bat, i notice that the inp is not passed properly. prompt command views inp and not the value retrieved from vbs. Thanks

```
For Each listElement In xmlDoc.selectNodes("document/Lists/list")
 msgbox "toto"
 inp=listElement.selectSingleNode("entry").text
 out=  listElement.selectSingleNode("output").text
 jeton=  listElement.selectSingleNode("token").text

 dim shell
 set shell=createobject("wscript.shell") 
 shell.run "job.bat ""a file"" **inp** "
 set shell=nothing 
 Next
```

Answer (score 3):

I think what you're looking for is this.

```
shell.run "job.bat ""argfile.ext"" " & inp
```

---

However, as [Ansgar Wiechers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15759171/1683264) points out, this is a potentially severe security hole, as a treacherously crafted XML file could run arbitrary commands.  To encapsulate your batch file arguments and prevent unintended consequences, consider switching to the `Shell.Application` object's [ShellExecute method](http://ss64.com/vb/shellexecute.html).

```
For Each listElement In xmlDoc.selectNodes("document/Lists/list")

    msgbox "toto"
    inp = listElement.selectSingleNode("entry").text
    out = listElement.selectSingleNode("output").text
    jeton = listElement.selectSingleNode("token").text

    set shell=CreateObject("Shell.Application") 
    shell.ShellExecute "job.bat", """a file"" " & inp, "path\to\batfile\", "runas", 1
    set shell=nothing 

Next
```

Answer (score 2):

Unlike several other languages VBScript doesn't expand variables inside strings. Because of that, `inp` in the string

```
"job.bat ""a file"" inp "
```

is just the literal string `"inp"`, not the value of the variable `inp`. To produce a string with the value of a variable, you have to concatenate base string and variable like [@rojo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15754722/1630171) suggested:

```
shell.run "job.bat ""a file"" " & inp
```

I would, however, not recommend doing this without some safety precautions. For one thing you should always put double quotes around your arguments, in case they contain spaces. I normally use a quoting function for this to prevent the instruction from becoming riddled with quad-quotes:

```
Function qq(str) : qq = Chr(34) & str & Chr(34) : End Function

'...
shell.run "job.bat " & qq("a file") & " " & qq(inp)
```

You should also *always* apply sanitizing to all user input that is passed to a shell command. Otherwise your users might wreak havoc by entering something like `foo & del /s /q C:\*.*`. Common practice is to allow only known-good characters in the input string and replace everything else with a safe character (e.g. an underscore). You can achieve this with a regular expression:

```
Set re = New RegExp
re.Pattern = "[^ a-z0-9äöü.,_$%()-]"
re.Global  = True
re.IgnoreCase = True

inp = re.Replace(inp, "_")
```

Comment: +1 thorough.  I'm curious about something, though.  You know with an `ADODB.Command` object you can do parameterized queries -- `cmdObj.commandText = "INSERT INTO table (col1, col2) VALUES (?, ?)"` and then `cmdObj.parameters(0).value = "val1"` and `cmdObj.parameters(1).value = "val2"` to prevent SQL injection attacks.  Can that same convention of building a parameterized query be employed for other things, such as building a `shell.run` command?

Comment: Not that I know of. You'd need some sort of escaping function to "defuse" potentially harmful characters, but I'm not aware of any such function/method built into VBScript (or the usual COM objects).

Comment: Actually, I just ran a test, and it appears that the `Shell.Application` object's [ShellExecute method](http://ss64.com/vb/shellexecute.html) successfully encapsulates arguments to prevent the sort of attack you're describing.  Might be safer than `wsh.shell`'s `run` method.

Comment: Too late!  I got impatient, so I added it to my answer.  `:>`