# Execute Batch file with argument through VBSscript

Tags: vbscript, batch-file

Scenario: To generate multiple reports from the database, we execute the batch file in command prompt like

`C:\program files> cmdbatchtest1.bat servername date Y Y`

With VBScript I tried to do similar:

```
set shell=createobject("wscript.shell")
shell.Run "test1.bat.bat", 1, True '''''able to execute batch file alone
shell.Run "cmd /K "& com_e & """\tp.bat""" & "&&" & c & "&&" & d, 1, True '''' unable to execute
```

Please help me to get this working.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Fuzzy Button when you suggest an edit please fix spelling mistakes and clean up grammar as well as doing the code formatting. A suggested edit should fix all the issues in the post.

Comment: I did fix a number of them (missed one I noticed after)... not sure what happened to them!

Answer (score 0):

In the line that isn't working, you're passing `&&` as arguments to the batch script. The command interpreter is probably trying to execute `cmd /k path\to\tp.bat&&server&&date`.  Try just changing `&&` to <kbd>Space</kbd> like this:

```
shell.Run "cmd /K "& com_e & """\tp.bat"" " & c & " " & d, 1, True
```

If that doesn't fix it, I think we'll need to see how your variables `com_e`, `c` and `d` are set.

---

Also, please be aware that `shell.Run` has potential security problems. Wickedly crafted values of `c` or `d` could cause this line to execute extra, potentially destructive commands. Consider using the `Shell.Application` object's [Shell.Execute method](http://ss64.com/vb/shellexecute.html) instead.

```
set shell=CreateObject("Shell.Application")
' shell.ShellExecute "application", "parameters", "path", "verb", window
shell.ShellExecute "tp.bat", c & " " & d, com_e, "runas", 1
set shell=nothing
```

See the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15753224/1683264) for more information.

Comment: The problem with `ShellExecute` is that it's always asynchronous, so there's no simple way to wait for the external command to complete.